# Reversing string using stack error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'top'|

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct item{
    char value;
    struct item* next;
}item;

typedef struct{
    item *top;
}stack;

item* push_item(item* head,char val){
    item *temp=(item*)malloc(sizeof(item));
    temp->value=val;
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
    return head;
}
void push(stack*a,char val){
    a->top=push_item(a->top,val);
}
void print_stack(stack a){
    while(a.top!=NULL){
        printf("%c",a.top->value);
        a.top = a.top->next;
    }
}
item* top(stack a){
return a.top;
}
item* pop_item(item* head){
    if( head==NULL){
        printf("Stack is Empty");
        return head;
    }
    else{
        item *toDel=head;
        head=head->next;
        free(toDel);

    }
    return head;
}
void pop(stack *a){
    if (a!=NULL){
        a->top=pop_item(a->top);
    }
}


void main(){
    stack a;
    int i;
    a.top=NULL;
    char st[10];
    printf("Dooner la chaine= ");
    scanf("%s",st);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(st);i++){
        push(&a,st[i]);
    }
    strcpy(st,"");
    for(int a=0;a<i;a++){
    strcat(st,top(a)->value);
         pop(&a);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to reverse a string using a stack. The push function is working and I can even print the items in reverse order if I directly print the stack.

When I try to change the initial string to the new string I get this error:

```
incompatible type for argument 1 of 'top'|" at this instruction " strcat(st,top(a)->value);
```

Comment: Why do you need the `top()` function at all? Why not just use `a.top`?

Comment: @e0k `top()` is a useful step toward [data abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)#Data_abstraction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all in your `for` loop, you are redeclaring `a` as `int`, which will be shadowing variable `a` declared as `stack` in main. So change `a` to something else:

```
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

As you are storing one character per node, `strcat` won't work for you as it expecting a `char *` as an argument:

```
 strcat(st,top(a)->value);
           ^
           char * is expected but argument is of type char.
```

As `top(a)->value` will be the stored character in the node, you can assign it directly to your string:

```
int j;
for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
     st[j] = top(a)->value;
     pop(&a);
}
st[j] = '\0'; /* Don't forget to null-terminate your string. */
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to end up with a problem in this particular case because

1. you re-declare the variable a in the for loop with type `int` which over rules the previous definition of `a` and gives you the error of an invalid argument.
2. you're passing the wrong argument type to strcat `top(a)->value` has type char, but `strcat` accepts `char *`
3. Even if you change it to type `char *` (by say doing `&(top(a)->value)` ) you'll have a problem because `top(a)->value` is a single character that is not null terminated, and `strcat` will not know when to stop copying from the source

What you probably should do is just access `st` via the array eg `st[i] = top(a)->value` and then null terminate it once you exit the for loop.